# Identify a fantasy board game from the 90's

Tags: identify-this-game

I had a game in the 90s when I was a kid. These are the traits I remember:

1. Some kind of fantasy game.
2. A big carton board consisting of two pieces: upper level and underground level.
3. The game paths were perpendicular to each other. There were carton doors that were set up all around the board. They can be unlocked with the card that has a key on it.
4. A couple of playing card decks.
5. As far as I remember only two usual dices.
6. There were a couple of figurines (not players) that were positioned across the board. Players had to fight them if faced. I remember they were plastic and nicely done. If I am not mistaken one was green and looked like the Grim Reaper, but not as tall.

Unfortunately, that is all I can remember. I played it in the late 90s, but I am from Ukraine so it might have been issued earlier than that.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I have found this game on the internet. It is called [Secrets of the Dark Lord](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/191394/secrets-dark-lord).

It was released in Russia in 1999, and I doubt that it was localized to other languages and exported to non-russian speaking countries.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are thinking about [Dark World (1991)](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/31/dark-world/images) and/or its two expansions:
Dark World: Village of Fear (1993)
Dark World: Dragon's Gate (1993)

Grim Reaper:
[image]

Green Arch-villain:
[image]

[image]

[more images here](https://www.pundak.co.il/forums/viewtopic.php?t=38841)

Comment: thank you for the tip. I am afraid this is not it. I remember the board looking kind of [D&D](https://www.hypable.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/dungeonsanddragons.jpg): the same palette, but no such variety -- just greyish pastel colors and simple pathways, like corridors (although the board itself was much bigger). The figurines were smaller, fatter and single-color.